# what is the cause of Accuracy difference?

Tags: weka, data-mining

I have a dataset of 2001 attribute and 63 instances while doing classification using Weka we can see that J48 have higher accuracy compared to Naive Bayes.but after doing PCA we can see that the J48 accuracy decrease compared to the first one that is first I got 82% and after PCA I got 72.5%.what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Decision trees select features.

PCA mixes features into components.

This makes feature selection work much less - every input feature influences (almost) every derived feature.

Don't assume PCA is a magic tool that solves all your problems. It can work - but it can also make things worse.